# AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'VERSION' python2 pip

Tags: python, pip, cinnamon

When trying to run cinnamon-settings python2 I see the following error:

```
hutber@hutber:~$ cinnamon-settings python2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py", line 619, in <module>
    window = MainWindow()
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py", line 247, in __init__
    for module in modules:
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/modules/cs_backgrounds.py", line 5, in <module>
    import imtools
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/bin/imtools.py", line 623, in <module>
    if Image.VERSION == '1.1.7':
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'VERSION'
```

I saw this error after installing `pip3 install streamdeck_ui --user install`

Comment: Probably you got new PIL version which is not backward compatible. Either you uninstall it using pip then `cinnamon-settings` will use the distribution package. Or make a troubleshoot step, open for edit `/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/bin/imtools.py`  , scroll to line 623 and change `Image.VERSION` to `PIL.VERSION` .

Answer (score 2):

This is a known versioning issue between cinnamon and `pillow >= 6.0.0`. You can find more info [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/8495). As a previous commenter said, you can find the error in `/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/bin/imtools.py`. However, changing `Image.VERSION` to `PIL.VERSION` will not fix the issue for `pillow >= 7.0.0`. You must instead change the line to `if Image.__version__ == '1.1.7':`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with python. You can modify `/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/bin/imtools.py`.

1. Make a backup of the file. i.e

```
sudo cp /usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/bin/imtools.py /usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/bin/imtools.py.bk
```

2. Open `/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/bin/imtools.py` with nano

```
sudo nano /usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/bin/imtools.py
```

3. Delete line 623 to 636. And shift lines 637 to 645 4 spaces to the left.

Before:

```
if Image.VERSION == '1.1.7':

    def split(image):
        """Work around for bug in Pil 1.1.7

        :param image: input image
        :type image: PIL image object
        :returns: the different color bands of the image (eg R, G, B)
        :rtype: tuple
        """
        image.load()
        return image.split()
else:

    def split(image):
        """Work around for bug in Pil 1.1.7

        :param image: input image
        :type image: PIL image object
        :returns: the different color bands of the image (eg R, G, B)
        :rtype: tuple
        """
        return image.split()
```

After:

```
def split(image):
    """Work around for bug in Pil 1.1.7

    :param image: input image
    :type image: PIL image object
    :returns: the different color bands of the image (eg R, G, B)
    :rtype: tuple
    """
    return image.split()
```

A check for version Image.VERSION 1.1.7 is not needed if you are using current version of PIL.